# Graph theory distance measures and other metrics based on edge attributes/weight

Tags: python, networkx, graph-theory

I'm building a graph which has cities as nodes and the edges are major highways connecting these nodes.

My edge attributes are length of the highway and estimates of time taken to travel from the origin to the destination nodes.

NetworkX has algorithms that calculates distance measures like Diameter (Shortest path between the most distanced nodes), Eccentricity (maximum distance from a node to all other nodes) and Radius (maximum eccentricity for the entire network) .

Is it possible to compute these metrics using edge attributes like distance in miles and time in minutes that I have uploaded to my network?

Comment: ... I don't really understand your question. A graph is a <Vertices, Edges> tuple. Giving the vertices and the edges is the same as giving the graph.

Comment: @user202729 Not in a weighted graph.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can calculate a matrix of all shortest weighted paths in the graph with:

```
shortest1 = shortest_path_length(G, weight="distance")
```

You can now calculate the eccentricity of the graph with:

```
ecc = eccentricity(G, sp=shortest2)
```

Finally, you can use the eccentricity to calculate the diameter, etc.:

```
diam = diameter(G, e=ecc)
```

Note that the shortest paths returned by `shortest_path_length` and expected by `eccentricity` have different structure (a list of tuples of (node, dictionary) vs a dictionary of dictionaries). You can convert one to the other with `shortest2 = dict(shortest1)`.

Comment: <3 <3 <3. Thank you! I'll implement this and get back to you!